# Django Ckeditor: How to change background color/styling

Tags: django, django-forms, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I am having trouble changing the background color of the rich text editor. Most places say to edit the ckeditor css file but that isn't in my django project for the way i'm doing it i think. Is there a way to change it/add styles in the settings configs?  or is there a better way to do this?

template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor.js">
    window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/';
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'links' );
    
</script>
```

settings file:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
             ['Link', 'Unlink'],
        ],
        'height': 200,
        'width': 750,
    
        'stylesSet': [
            {
                "name": 'Lead',
                "element": 'p',
                "attributes": {"margin-top": "10px"},


            },
    
        ],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom styles and custom class attributes to ck editor you can try this if you are using **CKEditor** at **Django** admin site than you have to add this inside your

```
your_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ckeditor/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/config.js
```

inside **config.js** you have to replace this

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.removeFormatAttributes = '';
};
```

and you are using your custom admin panel than add where you want use **CKEditor**

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
    CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
    CKEDITOR.config.removeFormatAttributes = '';
</script>
```

**NOTE :** after adding this all if you din't any output first run **collectstatic** command and than do hard refresh.